# Custom entity validation with Clean Architecture

Tags: c#, .net, clean-architecture

How can I implement custom validation methods [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-attributes) that require access to the database on entities in an application built using clean/onion architecture?

It seems that since entities are in the inner most layer, it has no way of using the `DbContext` which is in the outer most layer, but I might be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Maybe look at FluentValidation. Its validators are added to DI so they can access the DbContext

Comment: I do not fully understand what you're trying to archive. But I wouldn't write validation logic inside entity objects, I treat them as POCO's. So I would implement all validation logic in my controllers. A controller has to validate that data from a view is validated and also has to validate that a POCO can be written. When the logic grows you can encapsulate it into new classes which will be used by your controller.

Comment: How does your validation logic depend on database?

Comment: I want functionality like being able to check for unique names.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to resolve the DbContext from the ValidationContexts GetService(Type serviceType) method which will fetch the service from the IoC IServiceProvider

Try it like this:

```
var yourDbContext = (DbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(DbContext));
```

And from a clean arcitecture perspective you should put the logic of the validation in a validation service which is using the DbContext or an abstraction of it. You then only inject the interface that the validation service implements into the validation attribute.

```
var yourValidationService = (IValidator)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IValidator));
```